# Why does `git ls-files --modified` show files multiple times in a merge conflict?

Tags: git

When I have a merge conflict and type `git ls-files --modified` I expect that it will show the list of files that are modified in the current merge conflict, and show a file only once. But sometimes it shows the same file listed multiple times. For example, when I do the following:

```
git init
git commit --allow-empty -m 'init'
echo hello world > file
git add -A
git commit -m "hello world"
git checkout HEAD^
git checkout -b other
echo hello other > file
git add -A
git commit -m "hello other"
git merge master 
# Generates conflict
git ls-files --modified
```

it shows

```
file
file
```

When a git status only shows `file` once.

In this case it has listed the same file twice, but I have had times where it has listed the same file 3 times.

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git ls-files` is a low-level command (in the Git world, this is called "plumbing command") that shows the internal state of a Git repository. More precisely, it lists entries in the index.

When a merge ends up in conflicts, each conflicted file has 3 entries in the index: one for the common ancestor, on for your version and one for the version being merged. This is what allows `git diff` to show you a combined diff when you have unresolved conflicts.

As a consequence of the two statements above, it is logical to have `git ls-files` show several entries for the same file in case of conflicts.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a command to list a conflicted file only once?

Comment: I don't think there's a Git command for that, but at worse: `git ls-files -m | uniq`.

Answer (score 1):

This will be easier with Git 2.31 (Q1 2021): "[`git ls-files`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5198426d914ae15b52f85958c224a92f48e4f95e/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files))</sup> can and does show multiple entries when the index is unmerged, which is a source for confusion unless `-s`/`-u` option is in use.
A new option `--deduplicate` has been introduced.

See [commit 93a7d98](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93a7d9835f008488080d4f61096ee4c12ae60362), [commit ed644d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed644d1666415cbed14cc6cd17a658bb56e7f28b), [commit f1c462e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1c462ea4119f58a230abd62096a174483930a18) (23 Jan 2021) by [ZheNing Hu (`adlternative`)](https://github.com/adlternative).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5198426](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5198426d914ae15b52f85958c224a92f48e4f95e), 05 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`ls-files.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93a7d9835f008488080d4f61096ee4c12ae60362): add `--deduplicate` option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: ZheNing Hu</sup>
> <sup>[jc: extended doc and rewritten commit log]</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano gitster@pobox.com</sup>

> During a merge conflict, the name of a file may appear multiple times in "[`git ls-files`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/93a7d9835f008488080d4f61096ee4c12ae60362/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files))</sup> output, once for each stage.
> If you use both `--delete` and `--modify` at the same time, the output may mention a deleted file twice.
>
> When none of the '`-t`', '`-u`', or '`-s`' options is in use, these duplicate entries do not add much value to the output.
>
> Introduce a new '`--deduplicate`' option to suppress them.

`git ls-files` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/93a7d9835f008488080d4f61096ee4c12ae60362/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt#L84-L90):

> ### `--deduplicate`
>
> When only filenames are shown, suppress duplicates that may
> come from having multiple stages during a merge, or giving
> `--deleted` and `--modified` option at the same time.
>
> When any of the `-t`, `--unmerged`, or `--stage` option is
> in use, this option has no effect.